# Get detailed field information for a pgsql resultset in php

Tags: php, postgresql

I have been trying to get the complete meta information for the fields in a result set from Postgresql in php (something like mysql_fetch_field(), which gives a lots of info about the field definition). While I am able to use the following functions to find some information:

```
$name = pg_field_name($result, 1);
$table = pg_field_table($result, 1);
$type = pg_field_type($result, 1);
```

I could not find a way to get more details about whether the field allow null values, contains blob data (by field definition), is a primary,unique key by definition etc. The mysql_fetch_field() gives all of this information somehow, which is very useful.

I would really like some way to get that information from php directly, but if that is not possible, then maybe someone has created a routine that might be able to extract that info from a pgsql resultset somehow.

PS: This looks promising, but the warning on the page is not a good sign:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php

Also, I am not using PDO at the moment, but if there is no solution, then a PDo specific answer will suffice too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the metadata on you column with a query like this:

```
select * from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'regions' and column_name = 'capital'
```

This should provide all of the information found in mysql_fetch_field.  I'm not a php coder, so perhaps someone knows of a function that wraps this query.

Comment: It would be very costly to run a separate query for fetching each column meta information, don't you think? I can use something like 'column_name in ('..', '..', '..')' to do one query and then iterate over those results and merge the column meta information into the existing results, though, so thanks for this piece of information.

Comment: Sure, that would be more efficient if you have multiple columns. The information_schema is a set of system views that you can query like any other table.  I don't like the idea of having a different sort of tool for different databases, so the goal of PDO seems correct.  Is this an active project?

Comment: Yes, currently working on postgresql support in my open source software http://mywebsql.net

Answer (score 2):

All;

Was amazed to find pgsql does not have a column count routine in PHP.  The helps I looked up all got total count from "information_schema.columns", which is not what you want when doing cell by cell processing.

So here is a couple of quick functions to use:

```
// Test Cell by Cell
echo "Testing Cell by Cell! <br>";
$sql   = "SELECT * FROM sometable;
$res   = pg_query($sql);
$r_cnt = pg_numrows($res) or die("Error: Row Count Failed!");
$c_cnt = pg_numcols($res) or die("Error: Col Count Failed!");
echo "C=> $c_cnt R=> $r_cnt <br>";
for ($n=1; $n<=$r_cnt; $n++) {
    for ($x=1; $x<=$c_cnt; $x++) {
       echo "Cell=> pg_result($res,$n,$x) <br>";
    }  // end while $x
}  // end while $n

function pg_numcols($res) {
    $spos   = strpos(strtoupper($this->db_sql),'SELECT')+6;
    $fpos   = strpos(strtoupper($this->db_sql),'FROM');
    $lenp   = $fpos - $spos;
    $t_str  = substr($this->db_sql,$spos,$lenp);
    $x_str  = explode(',',trim($t_str));
    $result = count($x_str);
    return $result;
}  // end function
```

Hope you enjoy!

Comment: Not what we are talking about here. We need complete column meta info, not just column count and data. Please read questions carefully before you answer.